# Error al enviar por POST ionic 5

Tags: php, ionic

Hola tengo un problema con el envio de datos por POST a PHP en ionic 5 , el envio se logra con exito con algunos dispositivos moviles y otros  no  , no lo logro comprender que esta ocurriendo, por ejemplo mi dispositivo Samsung J4 PLUS  no ingresa al PHP mientras que un dipositivo LG si , les adjunto mi codigo indicarme donde estoy cometiendo el error.

Saludos

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { File, FileEntry } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CargarImgService {

  stack_aux: any[] = [];
  formulario: FormData;

  constructor(private file: File, private platform: Platform, public http: Http) {


  }

  dominio: string = 'ruta_servidor';

  /**
  * Este método se encarga de encapsular imágenes en un objeto FormData para el envio por http.
  * @param {array} fotos  Arreglo que contiene los URI de las imágenes seleccionadas por el usuario.
  * @returns {Promise} Retorna un objeto tipo FormData con las imágenes incrustadas listas para ser enviadas via http.
  */


  public  async  addUser(data: FormData) {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      this.http.post(this.dominio, data).subscribe(resp => {

        resolve(resp.json());
      }, err =>{

        reject(err.json());
      });

    });

    
  }


}
```

Comment: no tiene nada que ver con logcat

Comment: si mas no recuerdo el angular/http creo que ya esta en deprecated y se usa el angular/common/http mañana paso dejando un ejemplo.

Comment: Hola! ¿Te sirve la respuesta que escribieron?

Answer (score 1):

usa el HttpClient en cambio de [Http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/http) ya que el [Http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/http) esta deprecado.

ejemplo:

```
import { File, FileEntry } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CargarImgService {

  stack_aux: any[] = [];
  formulario: FormData;

  constructor(private file: File, private platform: Platform, private http: HttpClient) { }

  dominio: string = 'ruta_servidor';

  /**
  * Este método se encarga de encapsular imágenes en un objeto FormData para el envio por http.
  * @param {array} fotos  Arreglo que contiene los URI de las imágenes seleccionadas por el usuario.
  * @returns {Promise} Retorna un objeto tipo FormData con las imágenes incrustadas listas para ser enviadas via http.
  */


  public addUser(data: FormData) {
     return this.http.post(this.dominio, data).toPromise();    
  }

}
```

Comment: Esa palabra "deprecado", se entiende, aunque considero que deberíamos usar alguna en el buen español, según este traductor: https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/es/deprecated "despreciado" podría ser una alternativa

Comment: Querido @fredyfx, en este caso la traducción correcta de "deprecated" sería "obsolet@".

Comment: Creo que es la palabra que estaba buscando, gracias :) con respecto a lo segundo, si es que te refieres a mi, me pregunto si me realmente me conoces aunque sea un poquito... Me llama la atención la forma de tus palabras, espero que te vaya excelente y un detalle importante, el comentario que hice nunca fue en mala intención, buenas noches @Dabbbb

Comment: hola muchas gracias a todos , encontre la solución fue por temas de permisos de comunicación  , investigue bien y  el problema del envió de datos  es por la versión del android que se soluciona desde el config.xlm , en estos dias le estare pasando mi codigo para que lo analicen.

Comment: @EnriqueHuamani por favor, pon tu respuesta y acéptala. De paso te asigno  la recompensa (que expira hoy!)

Comment: Y se perdieron los 50 de rep. Lástima!